# Selecting first row for each group in cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I do a query in which I get multiple messages for each day.
I want to get the first message for the day(or any single message for each day).

Getting the day is no problem:

```
display datefloor(@timestamp,1d) as TT ,msg
```

But from here, I am not sure how to remove the duplicates, or group by `TT` and select the first one. There is no function `first` in stats to help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
....
| display datefloor(@timestamp,1d) as TT ,b
| stats earliest(b) as x  by TT
| display x,TT
```